# Dynamic access modifiers

Tags: reflection, programming-languages

Are there any languages that allow changing the access modifier of a given member at runtime?

For example for hiding/showing information depending on the context where an object is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Most languages can do this, but it often comes with a performance penalty.  For example, you could change the accessibility of a private constructor in Java with the following.

```
Constructor constructor = MyClass.class.getDeclaredConstructor(paramTypes);
constructor.setAccessible(true);
MyClass instance = (MyClass)constructor.newInstance(params);
```

Look at the methods available on the class object in your favorite language and you'll see a number of ways to get at methods or fields, and once you have a handle on those, you can abuse them to your heart's content.

Comment: I was aware of this solution but it only allows accessing private fields (they are still private) and does not allow switching any member's access specifier from public to private and/or vice versa.